# Using csv to write contacts in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I know there may be a silly mistake in my code but I am not able to get it.
I am writing code which takes user input and writes that to a csv file(actually a contacts app).

```
import csv
fields = ['Name', 'Contact No.']
def store():
    file=open("contacts.csv", 'w')
    g=int(input("How many contacts do you want to save?"))
    a=[]
    for i in range(0,g):
        name=input("Enter Contact Name:")
        number=input("Enter Contact No.:")
        a.append(name)
        a.extend(number)
        i+=1
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    writer.writerow(a)       
    file.close()
store()
```

So, the problem is that when I try to input more than 1 contact, the previous contact gets erased and only the last one entered in order remains.
I think the mistake is in list parts. Can you tell the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `i+=1` does nothing in this code

also you are using list.extend wrong, extend is like list.append but for joining two lists. it is working for you only because the inner type is a string which is also considered a list.
see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=extend

just use append again...

the real problem is that a is just a big list of all the contacts and I assume you want a row for each contact. so I would suggest you call the `writerow(a)` method inside the loop and clear every iteration. like so:

```
file=open("contacts.csv", 'w')
g=int(input("How many contacts do you want to save?"))

writer=csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(fields)

for i in range(0,g):
    name=input("Enter Contact Name:")
    number=input("Enter Contact No.:")
    a=[]
    a.append(name)
    a.append(number)
    writer.writerow(a)
   
file.close()
```